# Parcel Bundler crashes while bundling PNG

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I am making a game with Pixi.js and matter-js libraries. I am using Parcel Bundler (version 2.3.1) for HMR and bundling. The dev server works fine but when bundling for production the process crashes with following result:

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 44:  1511 Illegal instruction     "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

This is the command I used for starting the process (in build script in package.json):

```
parcel build src/index.html --dist-dir build --no-source-maps
```

This code reproduces the problem I am facing:

```js
import {Application, Texture, Sprite} from 'pixi.js';
import grass from './grass.png?quality=75';

const app = new Application();
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const grassTexture = Texture.from(grass);
const grassSprite = Sprite.from(grassTexture);

app.stage.addChild(grassSprite);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This will, of course, not work here. But this works properly on dev server and produces same result on building.

On searching online I found a few solutions such as deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and then reinstalling them, but it did not work. I also completely uninstalled Node.js and reinstalled it but there was no difference.

If I import PNG as WebP it builds properly though loses some colours, so I assume this is a problem with saving PNGs. I would be content on using WebP if does not lose colours.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: *This code reproduces the problem I am facing* No, it does not.

Comment: @connexo This causes problem in my environment. It means this is not an error with parcel itself.